# Can't find default Connection on TypeOrm Migration generation

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I've searched for this error on SO and Git, but I couldn't find an answer, is there something I'm missing here?

I'm trying to create the tables for my dev server, but it's giving me this error:

```
Error during migration generation:
TypeORMError: Cannot find connection default because its not defined in any orm configuration files.
    at new TypeORMError (blabla/src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
    at ConnectionOptionsReader.<anonymous> (blabla/src/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.ts:59:19)
    at step (blabla/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (blabla/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
    at fulfilled (blabla/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62)
```

My config file is stored at src/ormconfig.ts, an it's configured like that:

```
const config = {
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost',
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER || 'postgres',
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD || '123456',
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB || 'local',
};

const connectionOptions = (
  configService: ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>,
): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: configService.get('DATABASE_HOST') || config.host,
  port: 5432,
  username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER') || config.username,
  password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD') || config.password,
  database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB') || config.database,
  entities: [join(__dirname, '**/*.entity{.ts,.js}')],
  migrations: [join(__dirname, 'migrations/*{.ts,.js}')],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
  synchronize: false,
});

export = connectionOptions;
```

and this is my package where I set my typeorm commands:

```
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/ormconfig.ts"
    "migration": "npm run typeorm migration:run",
    "migration:create": "npm run typeorm migration:create -- -n",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -p -n",
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm migration:revert"
```

Is something missing? It is "debugable" with these infos?
As far as I know, everything seems right, I dunno what is breaking its compilation